# Returning multiple results from a partial search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to return multiple results when searching for a partial text.  I have item numbers in column A and item descriptions in column B.  I want to be able to enter a partial text string in to a cell O3 and return all results that contain that text in column D.  So, type in 'apple' and return with all item numbers that have 'apple' (apple sauce, pineapple, etc) in their description.  So far, using a formula I found on this site and modifying slightly, I can return the first result, but I can't figure out how to return the rest.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($O$3,B:B)),ROW(A:A)),COLUMNS(B:B))),"")
```

confirming with Ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Remove the IFERROR() wrapper and then copy downward. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

....figured it out.  It was incomplete and in the wrong column.  Here is the correct formula to return multiple results and display in a column rather than a row

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$4,$K:$K)),ROW($D:$D)-ROW($D$4)+4),ROW($V1:V1))),"")
```

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and drag down

Where:

- column `D` is the info I want to return
- `L$` is the text I want to search for
- `K` is the column to search
- `D4` is my starting cell to search (if you start in `D2`, you need to `+2` instead of `4`, etc)
- Row `V` is where I am returning the info